# C++ virtual inheritance with abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, abstract, radix

I'll try to make my intentions clear since there may be more than one approach to this.  To start, I have an abstract base class `FooBase` with a virtual function `SayHi()`.  `Foo1` is one of many derived classes.

```
class FooBase {
public:
    virtual void SayHi() = 0;
};

class Foo1 : public FooBase {
public:
    virtual void SayHi() {
        std::cout<<"Foo1 says Hi\n";
    }
};
```

I also have a `Component` class and sometimes I would like to implement `Foo..` classes as `Components`.  I've used a template class so that any subclass of `FooBase` can have a `Component` wrapper.

```
class FooComponentBase : public Component {
public:
    virtual FooBase& GetFoo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class FooComponent : public FooComponentBase {
private:
    T m_foo;
public:
    virtual FooBase& GetFoo() {return m_foo;}
};
```

Now `FooComponentBase` is an interface to components containing any subclass of `FooBase`:

```
void DoTest() {
    FooComponentBase* pFooComponent = new FooComponent<Foo1>;
    pFooComponent->GetFoo().SayHi();                            // "Foo1 says Hi"
    delete pFooComponent;
}
```

So far so good, this works.  But it might be neater if `FooComponent` were inherited from `FooBase`, so we don't need to go through `GetFoo()` to access `FooBase`'s methods.

```
// Inherited version

class FooComponentBase : public Component {};

template <class T>
class FooComponent : public FooComponentBase, public T {};
```

Unfortunately, `FooComponentBase` has no access to `FooBase` even though all of its derived classes do;

```
void DoTest() {
    FooComponentBase* pFooComponent = new FooComponent<Foo1>;
    pFooComponent->SayHi();     // Error, FooComponentBase has no SayHi() function
    delete pFooComponent;
}
```

I can't find a way to make this work.  It seems like there ought to be a way, maybe using virtual inheritance;

```
class FooComponentBase : public Component, virtual public FooBase {};
```

But that won't compile either, since we can't instantiate an abstract class. I hope my intention is clear, I'd like to make `FooComponentBase` an abstract base class, like `FooBase` but with `Component` inheritance, so I can use it to access every flavor of `FooComponent`.
Is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you use virtual inheritance in one place, you have to use it everywhere if you want that same base implementation to be used:

```
class Foo1 : public virtual FooBase {
```

The other way, which is not as nice but might work out for you, would be to implement all of `FooBase`'s functions in `FooComponent`:

```
class FooComponentBase : public Component, public FooBase {
};

template <class T>
class FooComponent : public FooComponentBase {
private:
    T m_foo;
public:
    void SayHi() {m_foo.SayHi();}
};
```

Or even:

```
class FooComponentBase : public Component, public FooBase {
};

template <class T>
class FooComponent : public FooComponentBase, public T {
public:
    void SayHi() {T::SayHi();}
};
```

Comment: That does it! `class Foo1 : public virtual FooBase` Brilliant, thanks :)